How to return a function value in a Class scope in JS?
I'm trying to write a random ID generator in order to use as an index to a Class that is going to persist users subsciption data into a database. however, I need to make sure this ID is unique to every subscription.
I could make the ID generator work ok, but for some reason I'm not able to return the given ID value to my application.
This is how I'm going through:
First of all I'm declaring the function generateRamdom that will create and also make sure I have single IDs by checking in a .txt file if the ID numbers has been already registered for that given value.
I'm using math.floor and math.random methods to generate random numbers from 1 to 100
There's a condition checking whether the generated number has been already in my database, if so, a message is sent to the user asking to try again. If the number is not in the database already, I write this number into the database repository and then return it to my application classe.
function generateRandom() {
function generateRandom() {
  let exitGen;
  fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', (errrs, repoNumbers) => {
    
    const randGen = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100).toString()) + "\n";

    if (errrs) throw errrs;

    if(repoNumbers.includes(randGen)) {
      const idMsg = '***id already exists. Please try do generate a new ID***';
      exitGen = console.log(idMsg);
      //return exitGen;
      }
    else {
      fs.appendFile('test.txt', randGen, error => {                            

      if (error) throw error

      exitGen = randGen;
      })
    }

  return exitGen})
}

console.log(generateRandom());

Here where's my problem lives:
when I call console.log(generateRadom), node is returning undefined when I should get the exitGen with the idMsg or randGen variables.
This values of exitGen are going to be used in a Class constructor in order move forward with the user  subsciption process.
any guess on that?
tried to write a function which returns a variable that respects some conditions

exitGen = console.log(idMsg); doesn't make sense. console.log doesn't return a value. Likewise fs.appendFile('test.txt', randGen, error => { ...  exitGen=... } means that exitGen won't have a value before the function returns

you should carefully reread your code; there are a lot of inconsistencies!
